# Is JS regexp engine regex-directed or text-directed

Tags: javascript

I'm reading about different regexps engines [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html) and there are two types of engines: regex-directed and text-directed. What engine type does JavaScript use? I assume it's `regex-directed`, but I'd like to know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link you provided, it is said that regex-directed engines only can process backreferences, given that JavaScript regexes have this feature, I'd says it's regex-directed.

Excerpt from the article :

> Nearly all modern regex flavors are based on regex-directed engines. This is because certain very useful features, such as lazy quantifiers and backreferences, can only be implemented in regex-directed engines.

Answer (score 0):

> You can do the test by applying the regex «regex|regex not» to the string “regex not”. If the resulting match is only „regex”, the engine is regex-directed. If the result is „regex not”, then it is text-directed. The reason behind this is that the regex-directed engine is “eager”.

A heuristics from [Jan Goyvaerts book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1411677609). 
Works for Python 3.7 `re` library.